# How to Count distinct rows over two ManyToMany Fields

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

```py
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
  users = models.ManyToMany(User, blank=True, related_name="groups"


class Task(models.Model):
  users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="personal_tasks")
  groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name="group_tasks")
```

*Note: Code above is to demonstrate the concept, it is not code that is being used.*

So using the models above as an example, would it be possible (with a single query preferably) to get a total count of unique users?

I initially thought of just adding the counts of the `users` field and the `groups__users` field, however, I would like to account for the possibility that someone was both assigned the task personally, and through their group.

Comment: so you want to get number of unique user in a group right?

Comment: Use Through attribute, Create One more table(which django automatically creates if not specified), Say you call it `GroupUser`, And Then use filter: `GroupUser.objects,filter(group=gid).distinct()`

Comment: @CharanjitSingh but OP probably also needs users from `Tasks.users` and combine those with `Tasks.groups.users` and then get a distinct.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r Yes, that is what I need to do.

Comment: The total count of unique users for *what*? For a single task? For each task?  How do you count the users? Only with `users`, or the ones in the `groups` as well?

Comment: For each task or for a single task are essentially the same query. As stated in the question, ALL users assigned to a task whether through a group or individually.

Answer (score -1):

if you use CBv  class based views !!

in Views.py :

```
class yourclass(ListView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = '....'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Count_Somthing'] = YourModel.objects.all().count()
        return context
```

in you'r template html  use :  {{Count_Somthing}}

OR

if you use Function : it's easy by useing filter

```
def Your_Fonction(request):
    search_for= YourModel.objects.get(any_fields= pk)
    Count_Somthing=search_for.count()
  return(request,'....html',Count_Somthing)
```

in you'r template html  use :  {{Count_Somthing}}

Comment: This is not the optimal one, Again this is of O(n)

Comment: and please read the question again, he's asking for query, not view